# How to create a Table Type with columns more than 1024 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I want to create a table type that should have more than 1024 columns. So I tried to use sparse columns by creating a - SpecialPurposeColumns XML COLUMN_SET as shown below. That did not work. It gave me an error: Incorrect syntax near 'COLUMN_SET'

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TempTable AS TABLE (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        SpecialPurposeColumns XML COLUMN_SET FOR ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS,
        col1 VARCHAR(10) SPARSE NULL,
        col2 VARCHAR(10) SPARSE NULL,
        .
        .
        col1025 VARCHAR(10) SPARSE NULL);
```

Is there any way that I can create a table type that can have more than 1024 columns?

Comment: If you find yourself running into limits like this, it's usually a sign that you're doing something wrong - are you perhaps embedding something that should be *data* in the column names? E.g. if those were your actual column names, it's suggestive that the right structure is probably `ID int, Col# int, ColData varchar(10)`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? The feature that allows a large number of columns *in a table* is Sparse Columns. Column sets are a way to set all of them in a single operation. Table types on the other hand are used as *parameters*. You can use an untyped XML parameter or specify a schema. To validate the XML data on the client you'll need that schema anyway

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this isn't an issue of limits, sparse columns can handle more than 32K columns. This is a table *type* though, which doesn't need (or support) column sets. A single XML-typed "column" could be used to pass the value that updates the column set

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#restrictions-for-using-sparse-columns): `A sparse column cannot be part of a user-defined table type, which are used in table variables and table-valued parameters.` You don't need them there. What are you trying to do? What problem are you trying to solve by using sparse columns? Whatever it is, there are other ways to do it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - So I have a Stored Procedure(SP) that updates a table (MainTable) with 1024+ columns. I wanted to create a temp table with 1024+ columns that I can use to store the values returned from several table functions and then later updated the MainTable that's there in the DB. So I thought of doing code reduction in the Procedure by using a data type instead of a temp table within the Procedure. But I think I'll have to create a temp table or maybe use another Proc that created this temp table. Thank you

Comment: @Macto you don't need a table type to create a temporary table. And *yes*, you can have more than 1024 *sparse* columns per *table*. You aren't reducing code in any case. In a query or stored procedure, the type is the table itself, with its schema, indexes *and statistics*. Stored procedures are compiled into execution plans based on the actual data statistics. If you need so many columns, passing around "tables" like this, you're doing something wrong. Are you trying to emulate document storage over a relational database perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Restrictions for Using Sparse Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15):

> ### Restrictions for Using Sparse Columns
>
> Sparse columns can be of any SQL Server data type and behave like any other column with the following restrictions:
>
> - ...
> - A sparse column cannot be part of a user-defined table type, which are used in table variables and table-valued parameters.

So you cannot use `SPARSE` columns in a table type object.

As for having more than 1,024 columns, again, no you can't. From [Maximum capacity specifications for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15):

> ### Database Engine objects
>
> Maximum sizes and numbers of various objects defined in SQL Server databases or referenced in Transact-SQL statements.
>
> | SQL Server Database Engine object | Maximum sizes/numbers SQL Server (64-bit) | Additional Information |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Columns per table | 1,024 | Tables that include sparse column sets include up to 30,000 columns. See [sparse column sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-column-sets?view=sql-server-ver15). |

Obviously, the "see sparse column sets" is not relevant here, as they are not supported (as outlined above).

If, however, you "need" this many columns then you more than likely really have a design flaw; probably suffer from significant denormalisation.

Comment: You can have at least 30K sparse columns per table. This was actually requested by the SharePoint team which, back then, stored list item "fields" as quasi-EAV data: for a single list item, there was one row with one field per "type" that contained delimited fields for all "fields" of that type. And they thought that 30K rows weren't enough. Not so much a design flaw (it was) but an attempt to treat a single *table* as a document store. Back in 2001, SP used Exchange's quasi-document storage engine, so they tried to migrate it to SQL

Comment: I'm not sure of your point here, @PanagiotisKanavos . I never said that you couldn't have 30K sparse columns in an object that *allows* them.

Comment: It;s `you more than likely really have a design flaw;`. As anyone outside the SP team would say, `Oh (redacted) YES!`. And MS salesmen. They didn't like hearing there was a design flaw

Comment: More than likely doesn't mean "is", @PanagiotisKanavos . We have no context as to *why* the OP wants so many columns. I would even suggest that a table having 1,000~ columns is likely a design flaw, let alone 30,000. Perhaps it's not here, but we don't know but it's far more likely it *is*.